# Can someone REMIND me how to ADD to a .css value using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I feel silly asking this because I should know it but I'm in a hurry and I also can't for the life of my think of the right term to put into Google to get the answer I'm looking for.

Basically using javascript/jquery I need to say "add varName's value to the existing css property of left:200px;" using the the .css in jQuery.

Comment: read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306523/change-css-using-if-in-jquery

Comment: What about `.css()` function? ;-)

Comment: No I'm using the .css function. That's not the issue :p It's simpler than that.

Comment: No I'm using the .css function. That's not the issue :p It's simpler than that. I actually just need to know how actually ADD the value of varName to the EXISTING CSS value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go through this

http://api.jquery.com/css/

```
//This will set or overwrite the left style property of element 
//selected by elementSelector
$("elementSelector").css("left", varName);
```

Alternatively `css` method takes a `map` if you want to set multiple properties at once.

```
$("elementSelector").css( { left: varName });
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to increment the current CSS value with the one in your variable?

If so, use this:

```
var varName = 20;

$('#element').css('left', '+=' + varName);
```

Comment: @Joseph Silber I never realized you could do that!

Comment: @Don Zacharias: It's a relatively new feature. It was introduced in jQuery 1.6, I think. It's in the docs: http://api.jquery.com/css/ (search for `+=`).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.selector').css('opacity', '0.5');
```

or, for multiples:

```
$('.selector').css({'opacity' : '0.5', 'width' : '100px'});
```

or, for a specific class:

```
$('.selector').addClass('className');
```

http://api.jquery.com/css/

http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Answer (score 0):

```
var extra;
//fiddle with the value of extra
$("#myElement").css("left", 100 + extra +"px");
```